# MultiThreading ManyToOne

Tags: java, многопоточность

И так у меня есть

```
MainThread. Controller
Thread-0. CustomObject1
...
Thread-N. CustomObjectN
```

CustomObject1, ... , CustomObjectN - это разные экземпляры одного класса CustomObject.class

Жизненным циклом объектов CustomObject управляет Controller.

Когда, у какого-нибудь CustomObject возникает определенное событие, он должен оповестить об этом Controller.

Как это правильнее реализовать?

Я думаю сделать в Controller синхронизированный метод push() и при создании CustomObject, давать на него ссылку

```
CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();    
сustomObject.setController(this);
Thread thread = new Thread(customObject);
thread.start();
```

а в самом Controller все передаваемые в метод push() действия, помещать в threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit() дабы их исполнение не мешало принятию команд от других CustomObject'ов

Что скажете?

Comment: Лучше давать ссылку на [очередь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) и передавать данные через неё.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо за ответ. Попробую, тогда отпишусь.